# How to get tagname of child element of a div or any?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagehead">
    <h1>Sample 1</h1>
    <h1>Sample 2</h1>
    <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
<button onclick="savetoJSON()">Save</button>
</body>
<script>
    var count=$("#pagehead").children().length;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        var ele=$("#pagehead").children()[i];
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I would like to get the tagname of all children one by one in a string format.I tried `.prop("tagName");` which dint work. In addition to this I would like to know how to convert [object HTMLHeadingElement] object to string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use [**`Element.tagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property, it returns the name of the element.

```js
var count = $("#pagehead").children().length;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var ele = $("#pagehead").children()[i];
  console.log(ele.tagName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagehead">
  <h1>Sample 1</h1>
  <h1>Sample 2</h1>
  <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
```

***Optimized option:***

```js
var pageheadChildren = $("#pagehead").children();
for (var i = 0, len = pageheadChildren.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(pageheadChildren[i].tagName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagehead">
  <h1>Sample 1</h1>
  <h1>Sample 2</h1>
  <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
```

***Using `jQuery.prop` :***

```js
$("#pagehead").children().each(function() {
  console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagehead">
  <h1>Sample 1</h1>
  <h1>Sample 2</h1>
  <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very inefficient. Every time `$("#pagehead")` is executed, a search on the DOM is performed. Why don't you just store it in a variable?

Comment: @Aloso — OP never asked about efficiency of his code, this snippet simply provides approach of getting `tagName` of element...

Comment: Every code should be efficient at some degree. It's a general criteria for code quality. It's not necessary to explicitly request it.

Comment: @Aloso — I have provided few other approaches as well.. I guess they are relatively efficient..

Answer (score 1):

`element.tagName` is the way to go. but note that traversing the dom each time you want to access the child is counter-productive :

```js
var children = $("#pagehead").children()
children.each(function(index,el){
  console.log(el.tagName);
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagehead">
    <h1>Sample 1</h1>
    <h1>Sample 2</h1>
    <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
<button onclick="savetoJSON()">Save</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to loop through the elements and simplify your code a little.

```js
$("#pagehead").children().each(function() {
 console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagehead">
    <h1>Sample 1</h1>
    <h1>Sample 2</h1>
    <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried `$(el)[i].prop('tagName')` that will fail. Try just looping your elements and list `$(el).prop('tagName')`

```js
function savetoJSON() {
  $("#pagehead > *").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagehead">
  <h1>Sample 1</h1>
  <h1>Sample 2</h1>
  <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
<button onclick="savetoJSON()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to generate your list as array

```js
var tags = $('#pagehead').children().map(function(){
   return this.tagName;
}).get().join()

console.log(tags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagehead">
  <h1>Sample 1</h1>
  <h1>Sample 2</h1>
  <p>Thank you</p>
</div>
```